# Problem with BottomNavigationTab in Flutter - refreshing widgets other than the selected tab

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

i have some problems when i coded basic layout namely, I found that when I choose a card two indexes away, a notification is displayed in the console, which in each of the tabs in the function at the start of a given widget, I wrote, instead of refreshing one tab, the selected one, it refreshes the neighboring one and finally the target one. I will post photos with the code below and let me know what's wrong! :)

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeScreen createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controllerInMain;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controllerInMain = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
    controllerInMain.addListener(() {
      _handleTabSelection();
    });
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controllerInMain.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Managly",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            MenuTab(),
            OrdersTab(),
            StatisticsTab(),
            EmployeeTab(),
            TableTab(),
          ],
          controller: controllerInMain,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: controllerInMain,
        indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        tabs: <Tab>[
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.restaurant_menu,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.receipt_long,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.insights,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.group,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.weekend,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Panel UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orWVT.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swQDG.png)